# In Win32, HeapFree doesn't return the memory

Tags: c++, winapi

I have tested about HeapAlloc and HeapFree in Win32 c++.

I have created private heap with `HeapCreate(0,0,0)`.

Next, I have alloced 100KB with `HeapAlloc(_heaphandle, 0, 1024*100)`.

The process memory increased about 100KB with some overhead.
I have checked this process memory with "process tab of windows work manager".

I have alloced 100KB some times.
So, I have got following result.

```
process memory : 1,312KB  committed:3472, uncommitted:258048, alloced: 0

process memory : 1,420Kb  committed:7544, uncommitted:151552, alloced: 102400

process memory : 1,524Kb  committed:11616,uncommitted:45056,  alloced: 204800

process memory : 1,632KB  .............                       alloced: 307200

process memory : 1,736KB  .............                       alloced: 409600
```

Next, I have freed memory with `HeapFree(_heaphandle, 0, pointer)`.

But, the process memory doesn't return memory.  I'm really curious when the process memory free.

I have got following result:

```
process memory : 1,736KB  committed:23744, uncommitted:876544, alloced: 409600

process memory : 1,736Kb  committed:126152,uncommitted:876544, alloced: 307200

process memory : 1,736Kb  committed:228592,uncommitted:876544, alloced: 204800
```

Finally, I have destroyed private heap with `HeapDestroy(heaphandle)`.
then, all heap memory free.

The Process memory goes to initial value 1,312KB.

If I use many memory, I am concerned to suffer from lack of memory.

Comment: Thanks Naveen for reply. I have tested again. You're right. But I'm still unclear. I have created another private heap like first method. If I use HeapAlloc with second private heap, the process memory increase. The process has enough freed memory internally by first private heap though.

Answer (score 6):

You won't suffer from lack of memory. When you do `HeapFree` the HeapManager may not actually release it back to the OS and might keep it for future allocations. So when the next time you do `HeapAlloc` it can allocate from that memory.

Comment: Thanks Naveen for reply. I have tested again. You're right. But I'm still unclear. I have created another private heap like first method. If I use HeapAlloc with second private heap, the process memory increase. The process has enough freed memory internally by first private heap though.

Comment: If I have many freed memory with HeapFree in first private heap, and I use another private heap, then is it cause lack of memory?